# I can't add child to parent nodes.. :(

Tags: c#, sql, treeview, schema

I want to get the database schema and list it all in Treeview. The parent nodes are the table names in a database and the child nodes are the properties of tables. The problem is the code didn't add the child nodes to its parent nodes. The output can be seen below the codes. Thank you.

```
public List<string> GetTableSchema(string conString, List<string> tblNames)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
                    connection.Close();
                    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                    {
                        tblNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
                        foreach (var list in tblNames)
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            string query = "SELECT * FROM" + " " + list;
                            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            dt = dr.GetSchemaTable();
                            connection.Close();

                            foreach (DataRow dt_row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                ## This Code is to add parent nodes ##
                                tViewUpdatedSchema.Nodes.Add(row[2].ToString());
                                foreach (DataColumn dt_col in dt.Columns)
                                {
                                    ## This Code is to add child to parent nodes ##
                                    tViewUpdatedSchema.Nodes.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", dt_col.ColumnName, dt_row[dt_col]).ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return tblNames;
                }
            }
```

Please click here to see the output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding root level nodes both when adding parent node and child node.

You need to first add the parent node, then retrieve it by index or key and add child items to this node instead of the treeview, for example:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("key","new Node");            
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Sub Node 1");
treeView1.Nodes["key"].Nodes.Add("Sub Node 2");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help .. I use that code but it gives me an System.NullReferenceException 

This is the code where i got that error.


tViewUpdatedSchema.Nodes[tempTblName].Nodes.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", dt_col.ColumnName, dt_row[dt_col]).ToString());